# Quantum: Toffoli gates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-groups, quantum-computation

How do I prove that a toffoli gate is a controlled CNOT gate. i.e,

$G_{Toffoli} = |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes G_{CNOT}$.

I am not sure how to approach this, thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to evaluate $|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes G_{CNOT}$ on all 8 inputs. That is, on $|000 \rangle$, $|001\rangle$, ... , $|111\rangle$. But recall that the Troffoli gate's action is $T |a\rangle | b\rangle |c \rangle = |a \rangle |b\rangle | c \oplus (a \wedge b) \rangle$. So it only flips the last qubit if the first two qubits are $|11\rangle$. So it suffices to check $|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes G_{CNOT}$ does nothing if the first two qubits aren't $|11\rangle$ and that it flips the qubits when they are.